# String types not allowed (at 'gravity' with value 'end')

Tags: android, list, listview, imageview

i want place an image to extreme right in my list and as per 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:gravity
I am trying to do

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_now_playing"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="end"
    >
</ImageView>
```

but i am getting above error.
please suggest solution[image]

Comment: which Android version are you working with?

Comment: use fill_parent for your textview or layout_weight=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That attribute value `end` is available in Android 4.0 (ICS) not below that.

*And second thing to set that you might need to set ImageView's heigh/width to `fill_parent`*

**EDIT**

then another way to move it to extreme right take `RelativeLayout` as parent for **row** and in `ImageView` set `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` and `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`

Comment: yes Frankenstein you are right this attribute working in Android 4.0

Comment: I did this
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
the image is moved to the right but not at the end..

Comment: @shankey then to move it to extreme right take `RelativeLayout` as parent for **row** and in `ImageView` set `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` and `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`

Comment: @Frankenstein : sir, I did it but still image does not move to extreme right. it is get placed at middle.